# Can we get a notification if the signer has not signed the document for 3 days?

Tags: docusignapi

We have a use case where if the signer has not signed the document for 3 days, then we want to receive notification on a webhook with some info about the signer, that a certain signer has not signed the document. Is there something in the eSignature API or on Docusign Account itself that can help with this?

It is very similar to the event notification we receive when a signer signs a document, but in this case we want the notification when the signer has NOT signed the document after a certain number of days.

One way to achieve this is to store the envelope IDs in our system once the envelope is sent and then creating a job that will poll details of all envelopes that are older than 3 days and still unsigned, but we want to avoid that approach.

**Note:** This is not to be confused with the use case where we sent the reminder notification to the signer.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, you'll need to check the envelope status after 3 days.

Your idea is a good one as an enhancement: a new type of trigger event could be added to the Connect webhook system.

You could suggest it as an idea on [feedback.docusign.com](https://feedback.docusign.com)